# Outbound Domain Enforcement extension error

Tags: email, domain

I'm getting the following error and don't understand what it means.  Can anyone explain what this means?

The Outbound Domain Enforcement extension has prevented the following From Email Address option(s) from being used as it uses a different domain than the System-generated Mail Settings From Email Address configured at Administer > Communications > Organization Address and Contact Info: contact@k9direction.org, jefftawater@k9direction.org You can add another one here.

Comment: is the extension running on k9direction.org domain?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea where the extension is running.

Comment: What is the domain name its running on?

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing when you get that error? It sounds like you have something configured to have two email addresses separated by a comma. Pick one and use that as the setting.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you send an mailing from CiviCRM and the selected From field domain is different from the domain registered in Administer > Communications > Organization Address and Contact Info > Email.

You have to edit either one.  You can edit the From options in Administer > Communications > FROM Email Addresses.   Find the one that is incorrect and edit it.

Sometimes happen that even though the mailing From field shows the same domain, it is taking another value.